# How to query for multiple vertices and counts of their relationships in Gremlin/Tinkerpop 3?

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I am using Gremlin/Tinkerpop 3 to query a graph stored in TitanDB.

The graph contains user vertices with properties, for example, "description", and edges denoting relationships between users.

I want to use Gremlin to obtain 1) users by properties and 2) the number of relationships (in this case of any kind) to some other user (e.g., with id = 123). To realize this, I make use of the `match` operation in Gremlin 3 like so:

```
g.V().match('user',__.as('user').has('description',new P(CONTAINS,'developer')),
__.as('user').out().hasId(123).values('name').groupCount('a').cap('a').as('relationships'))
.select()
```

This query works fine, unless there are multiple user vertices returned, for example, because multiple users have the word "developer" in their description. In this case, the count in relationships is the sum of all relationships between all returned users and the user with id 123, and not, as desired, the individual count for every returned user.

Am I doing something wrong or is this maybe an error?

PS: This question is related to one I posted some time ago about a similar query in Tinkerpop 2, where I had another issue: [How to select optional graph structures with Gremlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704043/how-to-select-optional-graph-structures-with-gremlin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the sample data I used:

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()
v123=graph.addVertex(id,123,"description","developer","name","bob")
v124=graph.addVertex(id,124,"description","developer","name","bill")
v125=graph.addVertex(id,125,"description","developer","name","brandy")
v126=graph.addVertex(id,126,"description","developer","name","beatrice")
v124.addEdge('follows',v125)
v124.addEdge('follows',v123)
v124.addEdge('likes',v126)
v125.addEdge('follows',v123)
v125.addEdge('likes',v123)
v126.addEdge('follows',v123)
v126.addEdge('follows',v124)
```

My first thought, was: "Do we really need [match](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/#match-step) step"?  Secondarily, of course, I wanted to write this in TP3 fashion and not use a lambda/closure.  I tried all manner of things in the first iteration and the closest I got was stuff like this from Daniel Kuppitz:

```
gremlin> g.V().as('user').local(out().hasId(123).values('name')
              .groupCount()).as('relationships').select()
==>[relationships:[:]]
==>[relationships:[bob:1]]
==>[relationships:[bob:2]]
==>[relationships:[bob:1]]
```

so here we used [local](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/#local-step) step to restrict the traversal within `local` to the current element.  This works, but we lost the "user" tag in the `select`.  Why? `groupCount` is a `ReducingBarrierStep` and paths are lost after those steps.

Well, let's go back to `match`. I figured I could try to make the `match` step traverse using `local`:

```
gremlin> g.V().match('user',__.as('user').has('description','developer'),
gremlin>             __.as('user').local(out().hasId(123).values('name').groupCount()).as('relationships')).select()
==>[relationships:[:], user:v[123]]
==>[relationships:[bob:1], user:v[124]]
==>[relationships:[bob:2], user:v[125]]
==>[relationships:[bob:1], user:v[126]]
```

Ok - success - that's what we wanted: no lambdas and local counts. But, it still left me feeling like: "Do we really need match step"?  That's when Mr. Kuppitz closed in on the final answer which makes copious use of the [by](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/#by-step) step:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('description','developer').as("user","relationships").select().by()
              .by(out().hasId(123).values("name").groupCount())
==>[user:v[123], relationships:[:]]
==>[user:v[124], relationships:[bob:1]]
==>[user:v[125], relationships:[bob:2]]
==>[user:v[126], relationships:[bob:1]]
```

As you can see, `by` can be chained (on some steps).  The first `by` groups by vertex and the second `by` processes the grouped elements with a "local" `groupCount`.

Comment: thank you for (also) answering this question! I decided to combine `match` with `local`, which does exactly what I want.

Comment: while the output is equivalent - one thing i'm not clear on is the performance difference between `match` and the multiple `by` approach.  i imagine you should test it out to at least ensure they are comparable. if you do that comparison, please consider posting a comment back with your findings.

Comment: Ok, I will. I, personally, see some arguments for `match`:

1) I find its declarative nature easy to grasp (I used SPARQL before) - I tell the graph what I want, rather than how to behave.
2) `match` is great for programmatically creating queries (e.g., I combine many constraints like the description one).
3) As I understand, match allows for query optimization. Shouldn't this be good for performance?

Comment: In my data, I repeatedly performed the following queries:

`g.V().match('user',__.as('user').has('type','user'),__.as('user').out('written').has('name','Paper A'),__.as('user').local(__().out('knows').in('knows').or(hasId(319528),hasId(41377928)).values('name').groupCount()).as('foaf')).select()`

...and:

`g.V().and(has('type','user'),out('written').has('name','Paper A')).as('user','foaf').select().by().by(out('knows').in('knows').or(hasId(319528),hasId(41377928)).values('name').groupCount())`

Average query times: `match` = ~4.5 sec, `by` = ~5.2sec. In my case, `match` is faster.

Comment: yes, it allows for query optimization and i didn't mean to make it sound as though i don't have confidence in it. i just haven't seen it in use enough to say when it will be faster/better/equal to other query options.  and if you come from SPARQL - i see why you would like it. i'm born from gremlin so it immediately looks kind foreign to me. :)