# how to return subgraph from gremlin that is in an easily consumable format for Java

Tags: java, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am very frustrated about very simple things when I try to do a single traversal and bring a lot of stuff from DSE Graph 5.0 at once using Gremlin..

In my simplified case I have:

- 1 entity with specific uuid
- entity can have zero (see optional) or more types
- I need to be able to return the `entity` and the `types`

What I have so far that works is very ugly :(

```
List list = g.V().hasLabel("Entity").has("uuid","6708ec6d-4518-4159-9005-9e9d642f157e").as("entity")
        .optional(outE("IsOfType").as("types"))
        .select("entity", "types").toList();
List<Edge> typeEdges = new ArrayList<>();
Vertex entityV = null;
for (Object obj : list) {
    entityV = ((Vertex)((LinkedHashMap) obj).get("entity"));
    Edge typeEdge = ((Edge)((LinkedHashMap) obj).get("types"));
    typeEdges.add(typeEdge);
}
```

each row in the list has the entity and one of the types :/

I am doing all this because Vertex doesn't come with populated `edges()` based on the traversal in DSE 5.0 Fluent API. So either I am stuck with multiple traversals or a single huge terrible traversal that is very difficult to deserialize in Java Objects or I have to pass gremlin queries as String but that will not return Gremlin Vertex objects but DSE instead :(

In my less simplified case I want to return multiple entities of the above with their respective types how can this be done?

Finally what is a good approach that will lead to reusable code for custom object mapping of a subgraph with different type of objects?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Since, `typeEdges` is a `List`, can I assume, that one entity can have multiple types?

Comment: I know this may sound like nitpicking, but for clarification: the DSE 5.0 fluent API does **not** decide what data is returned. That's the TinkerPop 3 spec that dictates the behavior.

Comment: Good point Alex! Although as we discussed on jira, depending on the type of query (fluent or string) passed there are different types of objects being returned Gremlin vs DSE ones. Plus transaction handling from DSE (with ```next()```, ```toList()``` etc) and not explicitly from the programmer imposes specific query style since after ```next()```, ```toList() ``` etc the query is sent to the server and ```edges()``` are not populated on Gremlin ```Vertex``` objects and Gremlin ```Edge``` objects don't have the properties of the ```inVertex()```/```outVertex()```  ```Vertex``` objects populated

Comment: I believe these are decisions taken by the DataStax team and not by TP3 standard considering how things are implemented internally and what the behavior is, regarding sessions, transaction and if objects will be returned non-populated or for example will be lazily evaluated. Of course the API and return types are imposed by TP3 spec. TitanDB had a different approach (worse for some reasons better for others) and had implemented a different flavor of Gremlin even if the API was the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Entity:Type` is a `1:n` relationship, then you won't even need `optional()`.

```
g.V().has("Entity","uuid","6708ec6d-4518-4159-9005-9e9d642f157e").
  project("entity","types").by().by(outE("IsOfType").fold())
```

The result will be of type `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

**UPDATE**

Following the short `toList()` discussion in the comments below, this is how you can work with a traversal result without storing the whole thing in a collection:

```
g.V().has("Entity","uuid","6708ec6d-4518-4159-9005-9e9d642f157e")
        .project("entity","types").by().by(outE("IsOfType").fold())
        .forEachRemaining(m -> {
            final Vertex entityV = (Vertex) m.get("entity");
            final List<Edge> typeE = (List<Edge>) m.get("types");
            // whatever ...
        })
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! You mean 1/n in the specific resultset or generally in teh graph? What I mean is that it could be that the same type is shared by two entities even in the specific resultset.. How about multiple Entities and their Types e.g if I get all entities and their Types at once ?

Comment: Btw it says it is a ```GraphTraversal<Vertex,Object>``` and not a list of maps so I did a ```toList()``` - also Types are Entities too and not a different Label.. so I think it is n:n

Comment: Each row in the result set is an `Entity` and then either its types or its type. The other way (from type to entity) doesn't matter. In short, if an entity can have multiple types, then we don't need to change anything.

Comment: the version you had before your edit is working fine - ```hasLabel()``` is synonymous with has for those inputs? There is still need of ```toList()``` at the end right? it seems you are missing that

Comment: `toList()` definitely returns a `List<Map<String, Object>>` for this particular traversal. If that's not the case, then you either modified the traversal or we have a difference between TP versions. I have doubts that it's the latter. Anyway, I know that you (should) know how to cast the result if the correct type can't be inferred from the traversal.

Comment: `has("a","b","c")` is a shortcut for `hasLabel("a").has("b","c")`.

Comment: true but your code doesn't have a ```toList()``` that's what I was saying - oh I am stupid this is for one entity ;) ! Awesome thanks! Once again :) Hopefully those q/a will be useful in 10 years from now when gremlin will be very mainstream haha

Comment: What? Gremlin IS mainstream.. What are the other things out there? Cy.., Cy.., Cyphy..? No clue :D

Comment: Regarding `toList()`: I never add that in my answers, since I don't know what the rest of the code is going to do with the result. Could be that you actually want to use `toSet()` or that you don't want to use a collection at all and instead just iterate over the result set, using `.forEachRemaining(...)`.