# How to traverse from a vertex using ordered edges and sustain ordering for two steps away

Tags: java, gremlin

I have this graph example:

[image]

What I am trying to do is populate ordered lists with:

- `outE("ContainsB")` edges ( expected edges: `[6,7]` )
- `out("ContainsB").out("ContainsC")` vertices ( expected vertices: `[1,3]` )
- `out("ContainsB").out("ContainsD")` vertices ( expected vertices: `[2,4]`)

keeping the ordering from `order` property of `ContainsB`

Here is what I have so far without any ordering:

```
Map<String, Object> map = g.V(a.id())
            .project("A", "ContainsBEdges", "CVertices","DVertices")
            .by()
            .by(outE("ContainsB").fold())
            .by(outE("ContainsB").inV().out("ContainsC").fold())
            .by(outE("ContainsB").inV().out("ContainsD").fold())
            .next();
```

---

I have something like that in mind although from small examples it doesn't work for the two steps away `by()` expressions :

```
Map<String, Object> map = g.V(a.id())
            .project("A", "ContainsBEdges", "CVertices","DVertices")
            .by()
            .by(outE("ContainsB").order().by("order").fold())
            .by(outE("ContainsB").order().by("order").inV().out("ContainsC").fold())
            .by(outE("ContainsB").order().by("order").inV().out("ContainsD").fold())
            .next();
```

---

later I do:

```
Vertex a = (Vertex) map.get("A");
List<Edge> containsBEdges = (List<Edge>) map.get("ContainsBEdges");
List<Vertex> cVertices = (List<Vertex>) map.get("CVertices");
List<Vertex> dVertices = (List<Vertex>) map.get("DVertices");
```

According to the Gremlin documentation I shouldn't rely on any ordering unless it is explicit `order()` so I wonder how I can traverse on ordered paths that start with an explicit set of ordered edges and make sure that things will keep working with next releases.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with a script to create your graph, so others can follow along:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV("A").property(id, 5).as("a").
  addV("B").property(id, 8).as("b1").
  addV("B").property(id, 9).as("b2").
  addV("C").property(id, 1).as("c1").
  addV("C").property(id, 3).as("c2").
  addV("D").property(id, 2).as("d1").
  addV("D").property(id, 4).as("d2").
  addE("ContainsB").property(id, 6).property("order", 0).from("a").to("b1").
  addE("ContainsB").property(id, 7).property("order", 1).from("a").to("b2").
  addE("ContainsC").from("b1").to("c1").
  addE("ContainsC").from("b2").to("c2").
  addE("ContainsD").from("b1").to("d1").
  addE("ContainsD").from("b2").to("d2").iterate()
```

Now to your traversal question (I honestly have no clue why you're trying to solve the problem(s) using `project()`):

> `outE("ContainsB")` edges ( expected edges: `[6,7]` )

```
gremlin> g.V().outE("ContainsB").order().by("order").id().fold()
==>[6,7]
```

> `out("ContainsB").out("ContainsC")` vertices ( expected vertices: `[1,3]` )

```
gremlin> g.V().outE("ContainsB").order().by("order").inV().
                out("ContainsC").id().fold()
==>[1,3]
```

> `out("ContainsB").out("ContainsD")` vertices ( expected vertices: `[2,4]` )

```
gremlin> g.V().outE("ContainsB").order().by("order").inV().
                out("ContainsD").id().fold()
==>[2,4]
```

Comment: i need to use project (from your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41306396/986160 to an older question of mine) since I am doing everything in a single traversal and I need to get all those pieces somehow at once.. so I dont need to worry that anything after ```order()``` will be returned in incorrect order right?

Comment: With `order()` you get - of course - a guaranteed order of elements. However, if you would traverse both edges from the `B` vertices (e.g. `out("ContainsC", "ContainsD")`, the order of `C` and `D` wouldn't / can't be guaranteed.

Comment: makes sense! one edge out though will preserve order correct? any counter-suggestions to project() ? So what I have written in my post is guaranteed to work??