# Can I somehow reuse Gremlin GraphTraversals code when assigned to a variable?

Tags: java, gremlin

I have GraphTraversals that look like that (attrGroup:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex,Edge> attrGroupTraversal = some code generates it; 
List<Vertex> attributeVs = attrGroupTraversal.inV().out(EdgeLabels.ContainsAttribute).toList();
List<Vertex> sourceVs = attrGroupTraversal.inV().out(EdgeLabels.ContainsSource).toList();
List<Vertex> targetVs = attrGroupTraversal.out(EdgeLabels.ContainsTarget).toList();
```

Is there a way to reuse attrGroupTraversal so I don't need to rerun the code that created it in the first place?

I am getting:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The traversal strategies are complete
>   and the traversal can no longer be modulated
>
> at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal$Exceptions.traversalIsLocked(Traversal.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.addStep(DefaultTraversal.java:274)
>     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal$Admin.addStep(Traversal.java:301)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversal$Admin.addStep(GraphTraversal.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversal.inV(GraphTraversal.java:384)

Comment: Methods are useful tools to avoid 'copy and paste' code.

Comment: Are you implying that I didn't think about creating a method to make a new traversal? :P What if I tell you that this variable is passed from other code so I can't actually make a method for it since its actual shape is not known in advance.. changed the code to reflect that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you `.clone()` your original traversal.
The following should work:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex,Edge> attrGroupTraversal = some code generates it; 
List<Vertex> attributeVs = attrGroupTraversal.clone().inV().out(EdgeLabels.ContainsAttribute).toList();
List<Vertex> sourceVs = attrGroupTraversal.clone().inV().out(EdgeLabels.ContainsSource).toList();
List<Vertex> targetVs = attrGroupTraversal.clone().out(EdgeLabels.ContainsTarget).toList();
```

See also: [Traversal component reuse](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/recipes/#traversal-component-reuse) from the TinkerPop documentation recipes.

Comment: I tried it and it says ```clone()``` is protected .. only if I do ```asAdmin().clone()``` it let's me compile which I am not sure what asAdmin means

Comment: As of TinkerPop v3.2.3, `.clone()` is the canonical way to reuse a Traversal. Which version do you use? I suggest your try cloning from the Gremlin console with a simple graph and iterate from there.

Comment: from external maven libraries I am indeed using 3.2.3 .. but the packages are fetched through DataStax DSE pom.xml. Still I am not sure why that would be a problem

Comment: `.clone()` is the canonical way to reuse a `Traversal` instance in TinkerPop. Could you think of more details that might be helpful?

Comment: "Not working" doesn't provide any pointer. Commenting with links to a solution rather than downvoting may be a preferred way to help.

Comment: The interfaces `Traversal` and `GraphTraversal` do not expose a public `clone()` method. [I've opened a ticket to add it.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2515)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

GraphTraversal t = graph.traversal().V().has("type", "COMPONENT");

GraphTraversal newT = t.asAdmin().clone();

This saved my day.

Credit: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gremlin-users/ltEYV-ShTYg/xf9s8k8SCQAJ

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are getting the exception in the second invocation of "inV(...)". The exception is telling you that is finished traversing.

If several gremlin invocations become expensive (which I am assuming is what you are trying to avoid) you could bypass gremlin (if the underlying graph allows you to do such a thing) and work directly with the java api.

That way you can pick and choose as many v and e as you need

Comment: this doesn't help - I don't care about the multiple invocations to the server and back at this point. I would use ```select()``` / ```by()``` to get everything in a single go like here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41304450/986160. what I want essentially is be able to reuse the same gremlin code which I don't know its shape and create new traversal results from an input that is being passed in