# Is it possible to re-use GraphTraversal object to build query chain?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune, java-client

I know that you can do this to add multiple vertices in a single transaction

```
g.addV(...).addV(...).addV(...).iterate();
```

But is there a way to re-use the GraphTraversal object to construct the query chain using a loop to add multiple vertices in a single transaction?
This is what I'm trying to do

```
public static void addVertices(int max) {
        // build the cluster
        //...
        //
        GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));

        GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> traversal = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
            traversal = g.addV("account").property(T.id, String.valueOf(j));
        }
        
        if (traversal != null) {
            traversal.iterate();
        }
    }
```

I've also tried the below, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528217/can-i-somehow-reuse-gremlin-graphtraversals-code-when-assigned-to-a-variable)

```
for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
    traversal = g.addV("account").property(T.id, String.valueOf(j)).asAdmin().clone();
}
```

but both methods didn't work, it only inserted one vertex.

I'm using gremlin-java client to insert into AWS Neptune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep adding to a Traversal right up until the terminal step like `iterate` is used. So for example

```
Traversal t = g.addV("test") ;
t.addV("another-one");
t.addV("one-more");
t.iterate();
```